# Node/Express not saving updated company information to DB

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, express

I'm very new to Node/Express, and trying to implement this block that updates a company's information.  I have a number of `console.log` statements that are tracking the variables throughout the block, and everything seems to be working perfectly fine until the last saving line.  What exactly could I be doing wrong?

```
// Edit company metric information
  editMetrics: function(link, form, cb) {
    Companies.findOne({ permalink: link }, function (err, company) {
      if (err)  return done(err);

      // Iterate through form fields
      for(var field in form) {
        console.log(field);  // Looks great

        if(typeof(company.operational[field]) !== 'undefined') {
          company.operational[field].unshift({
            timestamp: new Date(),
            value: form[field]
          });
        }

        if(typeof(company.user_metrics[field]) !== 'undefined') {
          company.user_metrics[field].unshift({
            timestamp: new Date(),
            value: form[field]
          });
        }

        if(typeof(company.economics[field]) !== 'undefined') {
          company.economics[field].unshift({
            timestamp: new Date(),
            value: form[field]
          }); 
        }      
      }

      console.log(company); // Looks great

      // Save & redirect to updated profile
      company.save(cb());  // For some reason this isn't saving
    });
  },
```

**Callback:**

```
CompanyModel.editMetrics(link, req.body, cb = function(error, result) { 
    res.redirect('/portfolio/' + link); 
  });
```

Comment: What type is `company`? Can you post the relevant code about it? Also - what does `cb()` return? We're missing a lot of info here.

Comment: It seems to be a typical misunderstanding of how to pass a callback as an argument to another asynchronous function. Try ```company.save(cb);``` instead of ```company.save(cb());``` and tell us if it still doesn't work or if you don't understand the difference.

Comment: Doesn't work/ don't understand the difference sorry.

Comment: Company is a massive object.  Sorry I'll try to add more info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the last line:

`company.save(cb());`

should be:

`company.save(cb);`

Basically you are executing the callback and passing the result to the save function, when you need to be passing the function pointer to the save function.

Also make sure your callback signature matches the node convention of `function(error, result)` so that you get the result value you are expecting.

Comment: So I added some more info to my original question based off of your answer.  I changed the last line to `company.save(cb)` and posted my `cb()` function above.

Comment: remove the cb = part of your callback and just use a anonymous function.

Comment: I removed `cb = `, and nothing seemed to change.

Comment: okay, then try logging the error and result values in your callback and see if an error is occurring.